# How to write a program in Python 3 to convert a name written in Latin to a name written in Russian Cyrillic?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a program in Python 3 that will take the user's name in Latin alphabet as an input and then transliterate the Latin characters into Russian Cyrillic characters and then print it. I have equalized each Latin letter to their Russian counterpart and then I thought about using if statements to execute the conversion for each character but of course it didn't work out, because when the user types in more than one character, the program returns the else statement. I need the program to accept input strings and print the counterpart letters accordingly one after another. If the user types in "David", the program should print Давид.

Here is my funny code:

```
A = "А"
B = "Б"
V = "В"
G = "Г"
D = "Д"
E = "Э"
YE = "Е"
YO = "Ё"
ZH = "Ж"
Z = "З"
I = "И"
Y = "Й"
K = "К"
L = "Л"
M = "М"
N = "Н"
O = "О"
P = "П"
R = "Р"
S = "С"
T = "Т"
U = "У"
F = "Ф"
H = "Х"
C = "Ц"
CH = "Ч"
SH = "Ш"
SHCH = "Щ"
YU = "Ю"
YA = "Я"
YY = "Ы"
a = "а"
b = "б"
v = "в"
g = "г"
d = "д"
e = "э"
ye = "е"
yo = "ё"
zh = "ж"
z = "з"
i = "и"
y = "й"
k = "к"
l = "л"
m = "м"
n = "н"
o = "о"
p = "п"
r = "р"
s = "с"
t = "т"
u = "у"
f = "ф"
h = "х"
c = "ц"
ch = "ч"
sh = "ш"
shch = "щ"
yy = "ы"
yu = "ю"
ya = "я"

print("Latin-to-Russian transliterator")
trans = input("Please enter your name: ")

if trans == "a":
   print(a)

elif trans == "b":
   print(b)
elif trans == "c":
   print(c)
else:
   print("sorry")
```

Comment: There is a subtle detail concerning character case management. For example, "Щ" may be transcribed as "Shch" (only the first letter is capitalized). Is it an acceptable input in your case?

Comment: Yes. As well as other combinations (Zh, Sh etc).

Answer (score 4):

use a lookup dictionary with regex

```
lookup = dict(A = "А",
B = "Б",
V = "В",
G = "Г",
D = "Д",
E = "Э",
YE = "Е",
YO = "Ё",
ZH = "Ж",
Z = "З",
I = "И",
Y = "Й",
K = "К",
L = "Л",
M = "М",
N = "Н",
O = "О",
P = "П",
R = "Р",
S = "С",
T = "Т",
U = "У",
F = "Ф",
H = "Х",
C = "Ц",
CH = "Ч",
SH = "Ш",
SHCH = "Щ",
YU = "Ю",
YA = "Я",
YY = "Ы",
a = "а",
b = "б",
v = "в",
g = "г",
d = "д",
e = "э",
ye = "е",
yo = "ё",
zh = "ж",
z = "з",
i = "и",
y = "й",
k = "к",
l = "л",
m = "м",
n = "н",
o = "о",
p = "п",
r = "р",
s = "с",
t = "т",
u = "у",
f = "ф",
h = "х",
c = "ц",
ch = "ч",
sh = "ш",
shch = "щ",
yy = "ы",
yu = "ю",
ya = "я")
```

now sort the keys from longest to shortest length

```
sorted_keys = sorted(lookup.keys(),reversed=True)
```

do an re.sub on any matches

```
result = re.sub("(%s)"%("|".join(sorted_keys)),
                # replacer function
                lambda m:lookup.get(m.group(1),m.group(1)),
                #input
                input("Enter Word: "))    
print(result)
```

by sorting from longest to shortest you will prefer longer matches, thus ensuring multibyte characters are properly interpretted

Comment: See my comment to the OP.

Comment: that would simply require changing the key or adding an alternate key that maps to the same value